# Do all kana have a large and small reading?

Tags: words

Kana are written in large and small versions with different pronunciations in the composition of words but I am not able to determine if all kana can be used in this way. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, upper and lower case kana? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Christer, シュムッツ

Comment: @Christer, カリフォルニア

Comment: So by lower and upper case you mean small- and normal-sized kana?

Comment: @Christer, upper and lower case.

Comment: We don't have upper or lower case kana in Japanese. っッゃゅょャュョ etc. are not lower case kana. つツやゆよヤユヨ etc. are not upper case kana. Just to make sure, are you aware that さっき, きょう are pronounced differently from さつき, きよう, for example?

Comment: @shoko, yes I realize that, however, I noticed that the o in California was written in lower case for example, so I am wondering if all kana can be written in upper and lower case.

Comment: カリフオルニア would be pronounced differently from カリフォルニア. And, we don't have small sized カ, リ, フ, ル, ニ.

Comment: Those small kana characters are called 捨て仮名 (sutegana) and are referred to as small script, 小書き.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no such things as "lowercase" katakana in Japanese. If you mean `ッ` as opposed to `ツ`, and such, please call them *small* katakana. I assume you mean this.

Not all katakana have small versions. Here is the full list of small katakana characters defined in the Japanese character set.

```
ァ ィ ゥ ェ ォ
ヵ ㇰ ヶ ㇱ ㇲ ッ ㇳ
ㇴ ㇵ ㇶ ㇷ ㇷ゚ ㇸ ㇹ ㇺ
ャ ュ ョ ㇻ ㇼ ㇽ ㇾ ㇿ ヮ
```

Very common ones are `ャ ュ ョ ッ`. I think you already know how to use these. If not, consult the easiest textbook you have.

The character `ヶ` is also common but has a different usage from others (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/352/5010)). `ヵ` is for the same purpose, but much rarer.

`ァ ィ ゥ ェ ォ ヮ` are relatively less common, but you will find them often used to approximate foreign sounds or old Japanese sounds (eg. ドゥ, フェ, グヮ).

The others are very rare special katakana used to write Ainu words (see: [Special katakana for the Ainu language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_language#Special_katakana_for_the_Ainu_language)) and sometimes Korean words. You can safely forget them.

There are of course small hiragana, too. But the number is much smaller because  we don't use hiragana to represent foreign words.

```
ぁ ぃ ぅ ぇ ぉ っ ゃ ゅ ょ ゎ
```

These small vowels are mainly used to represent long vowels in native Japanese words (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15062/5010)).

Comment: Hiragana should be included in the answer too as there is nothing katakana specific about the question. (ぁぃぅぇぉっゃゅょゎ)

Comment: @Christer これでどうでしょう？

Comment: Seems good to me. +1