# Does Japanese have characters in small size and in capital size?

Tags: kanji, katakana, orthography, hiragana

In English it's normal for the sentence to start with a capital letter. In German also. Additionally, there are classes of words that are written in German with an initial capital letter.

How is it in Japanese for:

- Hiragana
- Katakana
- Kanji

Comment: There is no concept of 'big' (capital) letter in Japanese in either hiragana, katakana or kanji.

Comment: There are large and small versions of some kana, but it's not for the same purpose as the languages mentioned.

Comment: @Leebho, What is the reason or the use that there are at least of some Kana phonograms in (two ?) sizes ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/do-all-kana-have-a-large-and-small-reading?r=SearchResults

Comment: @aguijonazo I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. I didn't say **the** Japanese anywhere. If I've said something wrong or offensive I'm happy to correct it but I can't see the problem right now.

Comment: @aguijonazo Ah, I see you're referring to my edit of the question. I didn't think what I wrote was particularly strange, but I've edited it so it is clearly about the language rather than the nation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not many scripts/alphabets have two "cases" like the Latin script does. The Latin (English, German, French, ...), Cyrillic (Russian, Ukrainian, ...), Greek and Armenian scripts have cases ([Indo-European languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages)), but most other scripts are [unicase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicase).

- [Quora - What are the languages that have both capital letters and lowercase letters? Other than English?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-languages-that-have-both-capital-letters-and-lowercase-letters-Other-than-English)

Japanese has two different phonetic alphabets (hiragana and katakana), but neither is "upper" nor "lower". They are used depending on the type of the word. For example, インターネット (the katakana word for *Internet*) is written like this, in all katakana, regardless of its position in a sentence. イ is always イ regardless of its position in a word. There is no such thing as "uppercase/lowercase kanji", either.

Some hiragana/katakana do have [small versions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44342/5010), but their role is close to that of Latin diacritics. Small hiragana/katakana basically indicate a variation of the sound of the previous character. Just as Ü is a variation of U in German, ティ is a variation of テ in Japanese (note that イ is small). This is very different from the concept of uppercase/lowercase or [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) in English.

You can read an introduction of the [Japanese writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) on Wikipedia.

Comment: It may be worth noting that all writing systems using cases (bicameral writing systems) probably have the same origin, namely medieval Europe, i.e., bicamerality was invented exactly once.

Comment: It is worth to note that "cases" are a concept in typology of writing system, not of language. The same language, say, Kazakh has cases when written in Cyrillic, but not in Arabic; Javanese has in Latin, but not in their native script; and so on.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I suspected that but could not find any source. Do you have any?

Comment: @brokenlaptop True, Japanese can have cases when written in Latin script (romaji). Somehow the word "script" did not come to mind when I was writing this...