# Small letters in Morse and telephony alphabet

Tags: kana

I've read many pictures on Bing about the Japanese Morse Code and the Radiotelephony Alphabet, but none of them seem to mention [small](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/do-all-kana-have-a-large-and-small-reading/44342#44342) letters.

Is there a way to distinguish between small letters and normal sized letters in Morse and the Radiotelephony Alphabet? If so, How should I do that?

By the way, How should the "long vowel dash" be pronounced? What about odoriji?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia/モールス符号#和文モールス符号](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7#%E5%92%8C%E6%96%87%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7)

> 拗音および促音については規定されておらず、通常の文字として表現する。例：「ヒャッカジテン」は「ヒヤツカシ゛テン」と送信する。

So generally there is no code for small letters and just use the 'large' ones.

As for ー,

> 長音「ー」 ・－－・－

I suppose symbols other than those listed in the above page are not commonly used.

---

[Google input](https://www.google.co.jp/ime/-.-.html) does support small letters.

> 「っ」や「ゃゅょ」のような促音・拗音は、従来の和文モールス符号ではサポートされていませんが、Google 日本語入力モールスバージョンでは、大きい「つ」や「やゆよ」の後に半濁点符号・・－－・を打つことで、促音・拗音を入力することができます。