# How to write long sound to emphasize words?

Tags: slang, orthography, spelling, long-vowels

For example, I want to emphasize the word しらない by saying shiiiiiranai, しいいいらない seems a little bit weird to me. How do you write this in japanese character, can we also write this in the form of kanji?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, writing it as しいいいらない is okay, but is relatively uncommon. More common ways to write this are:

- しーらない！
- しーーーらない！
- し～らない！
- し～～～らない！
- しいぃぃらない！ (with small ぃ)

Needless to say, don't use these in business settings or in formal letters.

See Also: [ー vs small kana vs long kana for writing long vowels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15062/5010)

Comment: しいぃぃらない なんて表現はない。

Comment: @takahirowaki ええぇぇ…マジっすかああぁぁ…

Comment: しかも、しいいらないは全然OKじゃない

Answer (score 0):

> 全然知らない。I don't know at all.

しーらない、知らないもんね is like female or child. It means "so I am concerned about that."